# Does openssl errno 104 mean that SSLv2 is disabled?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I want to check if my server has SSLv2 disabled. I am doing this by attempting to connect remotely with openssl with the following shell command.

```
openssl s_client -connect HOSTNAME:443 -ssl2
```

Most literature I could find on the Internet says if I see something similar to the following error then SSLv2 is properly disabled.

```
29638:error:1407F0E5:SSL routines:SSL2_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s2_pkt.c:428:
```

I do get the above error when connecting to my Ubuntu server with SSLv2 disabled in Apache Apache but when I connect to my Windows Server 2008 R2 server with SSLv2 disabled in the registry I get the following output and error.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
```

I can't find any literature explaining this output and error. If anybody could explain to me if and why this output and error means that SSLv2 is properly disabled, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

At least [on Linux, 104 is `ECONNRESET` for "Connection reset by peer"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h#n87) – in other words, the connection was forcibly closed with a TCP RST packet, either sent out by the server or spoofed by an intermediary.

I would try Wireshark/tshark on the Ubuntu server to see what actually gets sent. If the RST is real, it could be that the httpd process died – check the log files and `dmesg` just in case.

---

The [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/) website can show all SSL/TLS versions supported by your web server. *(Unfortunately, it doesn't even bother with TLS SNI...)*

Comment: So I'm wondering if the TCP RST packet is sent from Windows Server 2008 R2 when a client tries to connect with SSLv2 when the server has SSLv2 disabled

Comment: Your firewall is usually the one intermediary who sends the RST packet. But if that is not the problem, sometimes forcing SSL3 with the `-ssl3` option or using the `-servername` option can get past this.

Answer (score -3):

There is likely a mismatch between the ciphers that are supported by your server, and those supported by the recipient's server.

Comment: How does one confirm this?  How does somebody resolve it once they have confirmed it?  I know the answers to these questions personally, but others might not know, hence the reason they reason this question exists.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same error and it was related to interface MTU.
Setting the client interface MTU to 1492 (it was 1500), solved this error for me.

Comment: This might have solved your problem, but your issue had nothing to do with SSL cipher compatibility and/or configuration.  While this answer might have solved your problem, it is not applicable to the author's problem, since it is unrelated to this question.